# Applying pre trained facebook/bart-large-cnn for text summarization in python on a dataframe column

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

I am working with huggingface transformers(Summarizers) and have got some insights into it. I am working with the facebook/bart-large-cnn model to perform text summarisation and I am running the below code:

```py
from transformers import pipeline
summarizer = pipeline("summarization") 
text= "Good Morning team, I need a help in terms of one of the functions that needs to be written on the servers.. please let me know wen are you available.. Thanks , hgjhghjgjh, 193-6757-568"
print(summarizer(str(text), min_length = int(0.1 * len(str(text))), max_length = int(0.2 * len(str(text))),do_sample=False))
```

But my question is that how can I apply the same pre trained model on top of my dataframe column. My dataframe looks like this:

```
ID       Text
1          some long text here...
2          some long text here...
3          some long text here...
.... and so on for 100K rows
```

Now I want to apply the pre trained model to the col Text to generate a new column df['summary_Text'] from it and the resultant dataframe should look like:

```
ID          Text                              Summary_Text
1          some long text here...           Text summary goes here...
2          some long text here...           Text summary goes here...
3          some long text here...           Text summary goes here...
```

HOw can i get this ? ANy quick help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Have you checked out `apply()`?

Comment: Are you utilizing a GPU?  In either case, I recommend you try it on a test dataframe for say 10 or 100 rows so you get a sense of the time required.

Comment: nope.. I don't have any GPU .. it's on my local machine ( 16GB RAM) ..
Could you be able to help me to write a function so that the same can be applied to all the other rows ( say rowcount = 10K) ..?  

Or IS there any better / efficient way to summarize the text .. please help!

Answer (score 2):

I am working on the same line trying to summarize news articles.
You can input either strings or lists to the model. First convert your dataframe 'Text' column to a list:

```
input_col = df['Text'].to_list()
```

Then feed it to your model:

```
from transformers import pipeline
summarizer = pipeline("summarization") 

res = summarizer(input_col, min_length = int(0.1 * len(str(text))), max_length = int(0.2 * len(str(text))),do_sample=False)
print(res[0]['summary_text])
```

This gives back a list and prints only first output of it. You can recurse over the list (res[1]['summary_text']..res[2]['summary_text'] and so on....) and store it and add it back as a dataframe column.

```
df_res = []
for i in range(len(res)):
   df_res.append(res[i]['summary_text'])

df['Summary_Text'] = df_res
```

Use truncation=True as input parameter (where you input min_length etc.) for the summarizer if your articles are long.

**This will take a long time using cpu. I myself am looking for faster alternatives. For me XL_net is a usable option for now. Hope this helps!**

Answer (score 0):

this is my code to iterate through excel rows from column X and get summarization in another column Y, hope this can help you

```
from transformers import pipeline
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(wb, read_only=False)    
ws = wb["sheet"]   
bart_summarizer = pipeline("summarization")    
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_col=8, min_row=2, max_col=8, max_row= 5):    
    for cell in row:    
        TEXT_TO_SUMMARIZE = cell.value    
        summary = bart_summarizer(TEXT_TO_SUMMARIZE, min_length=10, max_length=100)    
        r = cell.row   
        ws.cell(row=r, column=10).value = str(summary)   
        wb.save(wb)
```